# Can't get jQuery UI Autocompete menu to remain open with UI 1.9.2

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

This seems to be a problem with autocomplete in the jQuery UI 1.9.x versions- Is there any way to keep the jQuery UI autocomplete menu open when desired after clicking on some items? In 1.9.2, no matter what I try, the menu just won't stay open, no matter what I try.

I must use jQuery UI 1.9.2. I've seen solutions for earlier versions of jQuery UI that work, but they do not work with 1.9.2.

This code works with an older version of jquery + jquery UI:

```
var $input = $("input").autocomplete({
    source: ['Hello', 'Goodbye', 'Foo', 'Bar']
});
$input.data("autocomplete").menu.options.selected = function(event, ui) { 
    // clear out old function
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nr757/

Similar code does not work in ui 1.9.2:

http://jsfiddle.net/Db9VE/

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#input" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    close : function (event, ui) {
    if (!$("ul.ui-autocomplete").is(":visible")) {
        $("ul.ui-autocomplete").show();
    }
}
});
```